# Gradle uploading files to repository in custom task

Tags: gradle

How to specify group id, artifact id and version when we try to upload using upload task?

```
  task publishJsonZip(type: Upload, dependsOn: 'zipJsonFiles') {    
        repositories {
            project.repositories.getByName('myDataRepo')
        }

        artifacts zipJsonFiles.archivePath

//      groupId 'com.org.data'
//      artifactId 'jeestla'
//      version '1.0.0'
    }
```